# Swap first and second columns in a CSV file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, csv

I'm using bash.  I have a CSV file with two columns of data that looks roughly like this

```
 num_logins,day
 253,2016-07-01
 127,2016-07-02
```

I want to swap the first and second columns (making the date column the first one).  So I tried this

```
awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' /tmp/2016_logins.csv
```

However, the results are outputting the same .  What am I missing in my awk statement above to get things to switch properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk -F, '{ print $2 "," $1 }' sampleData.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

Because default delimiter is space/tab.  Not comma.  Taking your original code, and adding a `-F,` solves it.

```
$ awk -F, ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' /tmp/2016_logins.csv
day num_logins
2016-07-01  253
2016-07-02  127
$
```

Stripping it down to `{$0=$2" "$1}1` gets same result.

```
$ awk -F, '{$0=$2" "$1}1' /tmp/2016_logins.csv
day num_logins
2016-07-01  253
2016-07-02  127
$
```

Comment: Set `OFS` to get commas in the output too.

Comment: And this one would leave columns 3+ alone, rather than throwing them away.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses [`xsv`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) instead of `awk`, but is useful if you have many columns:

```
xsv cat columns <(xsv select 1-4,6- input.csv) <(xsv select 5 input.csv) > output.csv
```